# Calling doInBackground multiple times on after TextChanged causes app to work slowly

Tags: php, android, performance, search

I'm trying to implement server side search in my app. When the user types anything in `EditText` I call `doInBackground` on `afterTextChanged`. The method `doInBackground` calls a server script (PHP script) which returns 5 values in a JSON object.

This logic makes the app slow (typing speed) when I start searching for the string as multiple `doInBackground`s are getting called.

Comment: you have need to call doinbackground process after input Edittext values fullfill at button or any thing those you want to proceed this

Comment: Any code or further information would greatly help to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: @abhay  : you can manage this by putting handler for about 2-3 seconds.

Comment: This is a really bad method to implement that kind of searching, you are overheading your server with those kind of requests, @BhaveshPatadiya said you can manage this by putting handler for 2 or 3 seconds.